# copyFileSync vs writeFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am working on file manipulations and came across this.

Tried to look for an answer online but havent encountered any good, precise answer.

Which of these is a more optimized way of copying a file?

```
readFileSync() -> writeFileSync()?
```

Or directly

```
copyFileSync()?
```

Also noticed that copyFileSync uses the original file's timestamp. If `copyFileSync()` is more optimized, is there a way for it to use the "copy time timestamp"?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer your however you could turn your question around 1) Do you only want to copy a file from `src to dst` and keep src fileinfo, then use `copyFile*` 2) If you want to do something than just copy from src to dst then you would need to `readfile -> transformations -> writeFile`, also you can manipulate fileinfo when you create the `filehandle` that you write data to so you could modify creation time etc.

Comment: The underlying `writeFile*`, `copyFile*` are methods that come with libuv platform that nodejs uses for IO, i guess you could maybe ask them. 

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/master/src/unix/fs.c#L1148

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to know that reading file content then writing it to another file is not the same as copying a file, a file is more than just its raw content, almost all files have meta data associated with them, and when you read a file content and write it to a destination, you lose that meta data. So if you want to copy a file, use the copyFile method, else you will have to handle meta data yourself.

Second, the two methods in theory should have the same performance signature, in practice though there might be differences between them under different conditions (different operating systems, different file sizes), however worrying about that is more of a premature optimisation. However for performance sake, its better to use the async versions of these methods.

The copyFileSync does not allow you to directly change the creation date of the file, but you can do that using `fs.stat`